# Ionic Cordova Windows 10 - How to detect soft keyboard

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

I have an Ionic / Cordova application which I (also) build for for Windows 10 (UWP).

On a tablet (eg Microsoft surface), I want to be able to shrink the application when the soft keyboard is invoked.

I have not found a direct way of doing this, so as a work around, I do this on an input focus/blur events, however, I would at least like to be able to determine whether or not a soft keyboard is being used, so I do NOT do this when running on a desktop.

Here is my attempt (which does not work)

```
    public static isUsingWindowSoftKeyboard(): boolean {
        try {
          Utils.logger.info('isUsingWindowSoftKeyboard begin');
          if (!Utils.isWindows())
            return false;
          
          let w: any = window;
          let touchCapabilities = new w.Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities();
          
          let ss = stringify(touchCapabilities);
          Utils.logger.info(ss);
          let keyboardCapabilities = new w.Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities();
          
          ss = stringify(keyboardCapabilities);
          Utils.logger.info(ss);

          Utils.logger.info('isUsingWindowSoftKeyboard end')

          return true;
        } catch (error) {
          Utils.logger.error(`Utils.isUsingWindowSoftKeyboard: ${error}`);
          return false;
        }
      }
```

In the above when I log out the `ss` variable (the only way I seem to be able to get any debug info on Windows), it is just empty, so I assume the call to `TouchCapabilities()` and `KeyboardCapabilities()` is just not working.

How might I be able to do what I describe above?

### Edit 1

I didn't quite go far enough. Even though `stringify` does not show anything, at least one of the properties are actually there (perhaps they are actually `getters`).

Anyway, the following DID return 1 for keyboard when running on a desktop..

```
 let keyboardCapabilities = new w.Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities();
 Utils.logger.info(`Keyboard present: ${keyboardCapabilities.keyboardPresent}`);
```

I also tried touch capabilities properties...

```
let touchCapabilities = new w.Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities();      
Utils.logger.info(`touch present: ${touchCapabilities.TouchPresent}`);
Utils.logger.info(`Contacts: ${touchCapabilities.Contacts}`);
```

These both did report `undefined`, but it does show that the property `touchCapabilities`  **IS** defined, otherwise I would have got a null exception when trying to access the two properties.

I now just need to test this on a tablet with a touch screen (which I can do when back in the work office where I have a surface tablet).

The one other avenue I need to re-investigate is the use of `getForCurrentView()` as in the following..

```
  let w: any = window;
  let vm = w.Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
  this.logger.info(`vm is ${(vm ? "defined" : "undefined")}`);

  let ip = vm.InputPane;
  this.logger.info(`ip is ${(ip ? "defined" : "undefined")}`);

  let inputPane = vm.InputPane.getForCurrentView();
  this.logger.info(`inputPane is ${(inputPane ? "defined" : "undefined")}`);
  
  if (inputPane) {
    inputPane.addEventListener('show', async ev => {
      this.logger.info(`inputPane show fired !!!`);
    })
  }
```

I did not get the above to work, but I do see `getForCurrentView()` mentioned in other searches, even in the context of `winjs`. Perhaps I was calling in the wrong place, so will try again. If this works, it would be better, as using the `show` and 'hide' events I could then resize the app even if the user manually closes the soft keyboard rather than relying on an inputs `focus` and `blur`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me. I may as well add the whole class. The "gist" of it is in the two listeners added to `w.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.getForCurrentView()`

I added the following service, and I call it from the main component `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Utils } from '@shared/utils';
    import { Logger } from './logger.service';

    /**
     * Manages the Windows soft keyboard showing / hiding and resizing the app when it is shown/hidden
     */
    @Injectable()
    export class WindowsKeyboardService {
      /**
       * Construction
       * @param logger - logger
       */
      constructor(private logger: Logger) { }

      /**
       * Call from main component once the view is visible, so we can get access to Windows Input pane
       * and hook up the soft keyboard handlers
       */
      public async hookupKeyboardHandlers() : Promise<void> {
        try {
          this.logger.info('hookupKeyboardHandlers');

          // Only need this for Windows. For ioS/Android the keyboard plugin does all this for us.
          if (!await Utils.isWindows()) {
            this.logger.info('WindowsKeyboardService.hookupKeyboardHandlers - not windows. Skipping');
            return;
          }

          let w = <any>window;
          const inputPane = w.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.getForCurrentView();
          if (!inputPane) {
            this.logger.error('WindowsKeyboardService.hookupKeyboardHandlers: could not get inputPane');
            return;
          }

          inputPane.addEventListener('showing', _ => this.onWindowsKeyboardUp);
          inputPane.addEventListener('hiding', _ => this.onWindowsKeyboardClose);            
        } catch (error) {
          this.logger.error(`WindowsKeyboardService.hookupKeyboardHandlers: ${error}`)
        }
      }

     /**
     * Raised when a Windows soft keyboard is opened
     */
      private onWindowsKeyboardUp() : void {
        try {
          this.logger.info("onWindowKeyboardUp");

          // Just half viewportHeight for now (until can find out how to get keyboard height - if even possible)
          let viewportHeight: number = window.innerHeight;
          let kbHeight = viewportHeight / 2;      
          this.logger.info(`viewportHeight: ${viewportHeight}`);
          const focusedElement = document.activeElement;
          if (!focusedElement) {
            this.logger.info('WindowsKeyboardService.onWindowsKeyboardUp: Could not get focused input');
            return;
          }

          let inputFieldOffsetFromBottomViewPort: number = viewportHeight - focusedElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
          let inputScrollPixels = kbHeight - inputFieldOffsetFromBottomViewPort;

          const ionApp = document.getElementsByTagName("ion-app")[0];
          this.logger.info(ionApp ? "got app" : "not got app");

          // Set margin to give space for native keyboard.
          ionApp.style["margin-bottom"] = kbHeight.toString() + "px";

          // But this diminishes ion-content and may hide the input field...
          if (inputScrollPixels > 0) {
            const content = document.getElementsByTagName('ion-content');
            if (!content || content.length == 0)
              return;

            const topMostContent = content[content.length - 1];
            setTimeout(async () => {
              let ionScroll = await topMostContent.getScrollElement();
              ionScroll.animate({
                scrollTop: ionScroll.scrollTop + inputScrollPixels
              }, 300);
            }, 300); // Matches scroll animation from css.         
          }
        } catch (error) {
          this.logger.error(`WindowsKeyboardService.onWindowKeyboardUp: ${error}`);
        }
      }

      /**
      * Raised when a Windows soft keyboard is closed 
      */
      private onWindowsKeyboardClose(): void {
        try {
          this.logger.info("WindowsKeyboardService.onWindowKeyboardClose");
          const ionApp = document.getElementsByTagName("ion-app")[0];      
          ionApp.style["margin-bottom"] = "0";
        } catch (error) {
          this.logger.error(`WindowsKeyboardService.onWindowKeyboardClose: ${error}`);
        }
      }
    }
```

`isWindows` has the following...

```
public static async isWindows(): Promise<boolean> {
  await Utils.platform.ready();     
  const result = window.cordova != undefined && window.cordova.platformId == "windows";
  return result;
}
```

And I call it as follows form the main app component..

```
public async ngAfterViewInit(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    this.logger.info('AppComponent: ngAfterViewInit');
    this.windowsKeyboardService.hookupKeyboardHandlers();
  } catch (error) {
    this.logger.error(`AppComponent: ngAfterViewInit: ${error}`);
  }
}
```